# Wininet POST and PHP returns Empty Variables

Tags: php, c++

I am trying to make a simple HTTPRequest using Wininet, then on the localhost, it should retrieve the information via a PHP File and save to disk. The `wininet` sends without problem but i get empty fields as response like this

```
Info :  IP :
```

My c++ Code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "wininet.lib")


void Request(LPCSTR Host, LPCSTR url, LPCSTR header, LPSTR data, LPSTR ip)
{
    HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, Host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

    HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequestA(connect, "POST", url, "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL,
        INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
        INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
        INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP |
        INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
        INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE |
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);

    int datalen = 0;
    if (data != NULL) datalen = strlen(data);
    int headerlen = 0;
    if (header != NULL) headerlen = strlen(header);
    HttpSendRequestA(request, header, headerlen, data, datalen);

    InternetCloseHandle(request);

    InternetCloseHandle(connect);

    InternetCloseHandle(internet);
}

int main()
{

        HINTERNET hInternet, hFile;
        DWORD rSize;
        static char ipa[50];

        hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
        hFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hInternet, "https://mytwpc.000webhostapp.com/ip.php", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
        InternetReadFile(hFile, &ipa, sizeof(ipa) - 1, &rSize);
        ipa[rSize] = '\0';

        InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

        char *buf = "John Oswald";

    if (buf)
    {
        Request("localhost", "/test/freeze.php", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", buf, ipa);
        printf("Transmission Successful\n");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

And the PHP code that is suppose to receive it on my localhost looks like this

```
<?php

$info = $_POST['buf'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$simi = "Info : $info \n IP : $ip";
$fp = fopen('dg.txt','a+');
fwrite($fp,$simi);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

And here is the output

```
Info :  
 IP :
```

Comment: First of all, use `getallheaders` to see what request headers your script is actually called with. If those seem o.k., output what `file_get_contents("php://input")` returns to check on the request body, too.

Comment: Where are you setting the request parameter keys `buf` and `ip` in your code?

Comment: @CBroe, when i use file_get_contents it just shows John Oswald in the textfile, no IP address